# How to pass data with Mongoose to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

My relevant code is split into three files:

user.server.model.js:

```
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        ...            
        devices: []
    });

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

users.server.controller.js:

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User') 

var devices = 123;

exports.getDevices = function(req, res, next) { 
    User.findOne({
            _id: req.user.id
        },
        function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            else {
                devices = req.user.devices;
                res.json(devices)                       
            }
        }
    )
}

exports.devices = devices;
```

index.server.controller.js:

```
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller')

exports.render = function(req, res) {   
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'MEAN MVC',
        user: req.user ? req.user.name: '',
        device: users.devices
    });
};
```

I am using node.js, mongoose, mongodb, express, embeddedjs.

What I need to do is to get the **devices array** and pass it down one way or other to my index page where can I then handle it there with ejs. As I am not experienced in JavaScript, I did not find a clear solution, so I decided to pass the data to a global variable **'devices'**, then pass it to index page controller.

Now the problem I am facing is that **getDevices** function does not change the global variable **'devices'**. What I know for sure, is that **res.json(devices)** gives a correct result of **devices array** in plain json and that the default value (123) of the global variable **'devices'** is passed down to my index page controller and rendered in page.

Any other suggestion how my need should be solved is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`devices` isn't a global variable: it's only accessible from within the file that contains it, in your case `users.server.controller.js`.

You need to export `devices`, just like you do with the `getDevices` method. In `users.server.controller.js`, do `exports.devices = 123` and `exports.devices = req.user.devices`. Then, `users.devices` will work correctly in `index.server.controller.js`.

EDIT: However returning a value from a method like that is not a very good/elegant solution, it seems like `getDevices` should be returning the devices array. If the reason you decided to do it like this is because Mongoose's `findOne` returns the result in a callback, consider using another callback at the `getDevices` level or look into promises.

Comment: @NeymusLastneymus `{object Object}` is what you get  when you try to convert an object to a string. `users.devices` is a javascript object, not JSON.

If what you mean is that you want to convert it *to* JSON, you can use  `JSON.stringify`. However you shouldn't need to do that for `res.json()` - already does that for you.